suspected flutter_launcher_icons 0.14.1 causing FATAL EXCEPTION: wmshell.splashworker
I'm trying to use flutter_launcher_icons 0.14.1 to create launcher icon for my flutter app. I followed the instructions in the pubdev of it,
and when i ran dart run flutter_launcher_icons, this is the output
Built flutter_launcher_icons:flutter_launcher_icons.
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.14.1)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════

• Creating default icons Android
• Overwriting the default Android launcher icon with a new icon
• Creating mipmap xml file Android
• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon
Creating Icons for Web...
Creating Icons for Windows...
Creating Icons for MacOS...

Creating Icons for Web...
Creating Icons for Windows...
Creating Icons for MacOS...

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons

So i guessed everything must be fine, but when i run the app again this error shows:
E/AndroidRuntime(23044): FATAL EXCEPTION: wmshell.splashworker
E/AndroidRuntime(23044): Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 23044
E/AndroidRuntime(23044): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.draw(android.graphics.Canvas)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at com.android.wm.shell.startingsurface.SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory$AdaptiveForegroundDrawable.draw(SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory.java:269)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at com.android.wm.shell.startingsurface.SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory$ImmobileIconDrawable.preDrawIcon(SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory.java:131)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at com.android.wm.shell.startingsurface.SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory$ImmobileIconDrawable.lambda$new$1(SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at com.android.wm.shell.startingsurface.SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory$ImmobileIconDrawable.$r8$lambda$0odOtiiVhAkJamazINpBnODkLdw(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at com.android.wm.shell.startingsurface.SplashscreenIconDrawableFactory$ImmobileIconDrawable$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
E/AndroidRuntime(23044):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

This is my pubspec.yaml
name: activity_app
description: 'A new Flutter project.'
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.1
  http: ^1.2.1
  provider: ^6.1.2
  table_calendar: ^3.1.1
  intl: ^0.19.0
  bottom_picker: ^2.7.0
  crypto: ^3.0.3
  shared_preferences: ^2.3.2
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.4
  url_launcher: ^6.3.0
  firebase_core: ^3.6.0
  firebase_messaging: ^15.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.1

flutter_launcher_icons:
  image_path_android: 'assets/cm_launcher_icon.png'
  image_path_ios: 'assets/cm_launcher_icon.png'
  android: true
  ios: true
  min_sdk_android: 21
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: 'assets/cm_launcher_icon.png'
    background_color: '#F9F9F9'
    theme_color: '#F9F9F9'
  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: 'assets/cm_launcher_icon.png'
    icon_size: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: 'assets/cm_launcher_icon.png'

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/cm_launcher_icon.png
    - assets/cm_logo.webp
    - assets/cm_icon.webp
    - assets/cm_and_nu_icon.webp

I've tried flutter clean -> flutter pub get -> dart run flutter_launcher_icons -> run the flutter app, the error is still showing and the launcher icon is the android logo. I've tried to chatgpt and claude this but they can't seem to figure it out.

As i mentioned in the other reply i also had unexpected behavior with this since version 0.14.1. Your solution fixed the issue and fixed all unexpected behavior. Thank you for your contribution.

found the solution in https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues/595
remove the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder in android/app/src/main/res

omgggg this is 1000% the right answer. I have been stuck on this same problem since two days ago as well and this fixed it. I would also like to add that with the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder present, not only my app would have neither a splash screen nor an app icon, i could not open the system settings in android to uninstall or force stop the app. It would crash the system settings app! this is a major issue that should be addressed fast because this package is very popular and will impact several developers.

it worked for me also, thanks

Very good friend, it worked here

Super; thank you!

I'm not sure if it is should be necessary, but on Android you can also specify the adaptive icon foreground and background.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons#android
Which are themed icons for Android 13+. On what Android version are you running your app? If it is 13/14, it might be worth it to try adding adaptive icon specs to your configuration/running on an older device/emulator to see if it works there.
